# User persistance using FB login using Parse in Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I am using Parse and Facebook login currently. I have integrated both in my app and works fine. Now I have my SignIn page as my initial view controller. So when the user login using Facebook, he is able to use the app. The next time the user open the app, it still shows the login page. I dont want that. I want to redirect him to another page. how can I achieve it.

**My LogInViewContoller has only this button click**

```
@IBAction func fbLoginButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var permissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]

    // loginView.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
            } else {
                println("User logged in through Facebook!")
            }
        } else {
            println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
    }
}
```

**My Appdelegate**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?,annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
        application,
        openURL: url,
        sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
        annotation: annotation)
}
```

Now what I want is that the next time, the user open my app, he should not see the login page, should directly go inside the app. how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is after log in you can persist the status somewhere to determine if user is logging. So, every time app is opened, in app delegate, just check that status to switch to appropriate view controller. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: can you say technically ?